# How to pass json data to .js files

Tags: javascript, php, json

i got a problem here .

I have this code to create the json data in locations.php

```
<?php
    $locations = array(
            array('2479 Murphy Court', "Minneapolis, MN 55402", "$36,000", 48.87, 2.29, "property-detail.html", "assets/img/properties/property-01.jpg", "assets/img/property-types/apartment.png"),
            array('3398 Lodgeville Road', "Golden Valley, MN 55427", "$28,000", 48.866876, 2.309639, "property-detail.html", "assets/img/properties/property-02.jpg", "assets/img/property-types/apartment.png")
        );
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var locations = "<?= json_encode($locations) ?>";
</script>
```

I want to pass the json to locations.js . Which it will called by another .js file with getScript function. I tried to call the locations.php but its not working, so i create locations.js to test and it works

Not working

```
$.getScript("assets/php/locations.php", function(){
```

Working

```
$.getScript("assets/js/locations.js", function(){
```

locations.js

```
var locations = [
    ['2479 Murphy Court', "Minneapolis, MN 55402", "$36,000", 48.87, 2.29, "property-detail.html", "assets/img/properties/property-01.jpg", "assets/img/property-types/apartment.png"],
    ['3398 Lodgeville Road', "Golden Valley, MN 55427", "$28,000", 48.866876, 2.309639, "property-detail.html", "assets/img/properties/property-02.jpg", "assets/img/property-types/apartment.png"],
];
```

Can anyone help me? Thank you.
Sorry for bad english and maybe hard to understand

Comment: It may not get accepted because you don't have the Content-Type header set to `text/javascript`. Do a `header('Content-Type: text/javascript');` at the top of the PHP file.

Comment: @NarendraSisodia the problem is i cant make it work with locations.php

Comment: @CamilStaps still not working, is there any solutions? but thanks for the suggestion :D

Comment: Do my suggestion, but also remove the `script` tag. The output of the location.php should be the same as of locations.js.

Comment: @KhrisnaGunanasurya you were encoding it within script thats why its not working within locations.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im not sure to understand well what you need. 
Your PHP file need to ouput the JSON object :
location.php

```
    <?php

$locations = array(
    array('2479 Murphy Court', "Minneapolis, MN 55402", "$36,000", 48.87, 2.29, "property-detail.html", "assets/img/properties/property-01.jpg", "assets/img/property-types/apartment.png"),
    array('3398 Lodgeville Road', "Golden Valley, MN 55427", "$28,000", 48.866876, 2.309639, "property-detail.html", "assets/img/properties/property-02.jpg", "assets/img/property-types/apartment.png")
);
header('Content-Type: application/json');
die(json_encode($locations));

    ?>
```

Then you can load it with jquery

```
$.getJSON("location.php", function(data) {
  // do whatever you want with data
  console.log(data);
});
```

If you want to load the script that location.php output

```
<?php
    $locations = array(
            array('2479 Murphy Court', "Minneapolis, MN 55402", "$36,000", 48.87, 2.29, "property-detail.html", "assets/img/properties/property-01.jpg", "assets/img/property-types/apartment.png"),
            array('3398 Lodgeville Road', "Golden Valley, MN 55427", "$28,000", 48.866876, 2.309639, "property-detail.html", "assets/img/properties/property-02.jpg", "assets/img/property-types/apartment.png")
        );
?>
var locations = <?= json_encode($locations) ?>;
```

Then you can load it via jQuery.getScript.

Comment: it work with location.js because location.js is a valid javascript file. Try to run your location.php file, save the output as .js file and reference it in your main page, it will trigger an error meaning that you have syntax errors. A js file must not contain <script></script> tag.

Comment: Thankyou so much i tried the last one and everything just works fine .. So many thanks ^^

Comment: You forgot to mention that you also removed the quotes surrounding the variable `locations`'s value.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, remove the `script` tag from the PHP file. Its output should look similar to your locations.js.

If it still doesn't work after that, it may be you need to set the `Content-Type` header. Add, in the top of your PHP file:

```
header('Content-Type: text/javascript');
```

This line should go *before* anything is sent to the output stream.